# client side directory detection

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows, batch-file

Just a general question. I'm going to be creating a site and one
thing that I will have to do is create a .bat file, that the user can
download which is tied into a piece of software on their machine.

When the user is 'registering', one thing I would like to do is to be
able to have the user select which where their specific directory is for audio files.

This is no different then clicking on "browse" for an upload and then selecting
the file to be uploaded. But instead of getting the file, I'd like to be able to
just collect the directory. The reason for his is because inside the bat file is
an ftp command to upload an mp3 file to a server. I'd like to build the bat file
on the fly for them as they register and fill in the blank area with their directory
they have chosen. They then download the bat file and add the command line into
the software to execute the bat file, which then uploads the newly created mp3 file
to a server.

So is there a way to detect and collect the client side directory?

Comment: No. Consider an evil coder; I want to get your "Documents" folder... how would you stop me if there was a way for me to detect and collect the client side directory?

Comment: Elliot, one way I thought about getting around this if it wasn't possible was to simply have them type in their directory with specific instructions how to enter in the right details. The reason for it is because the bat file contains ftp details for their own specific directory that is created when they register on the server.

Comment: I understand, but the security model won't allow it for the reason I gave you.

Comment: You could have the user download a standalone program, and use that to register for them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
@Echo off
setlocal
Call :BrowseFolder "Choose Music folder" "C:\" r
echo %r%
pause
Goto :EOF


:BrowseFolder
setlocal
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs% echo set sh=wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
>>%vbs% echo set f=sh.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
>>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then 
>>%vbs% echo   wscript.echo "Dialog Cancelled" 
>>%vbs% echo   wscript.Quit(1) 
>>%vbs% echo end if 
>>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
>>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo p
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do set result=%%a
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
if "%result%" EQU "Dialog Cancelled" (set a=1) else set a=0
endlocal & set %3=%result% & exit /b %a%
```

Comment: That's awesome! It may be enough to help them at least detect the proper directory that they can then type in to the site! :) I will accept that answer! Thanks Matt!

Comment: Matt, can I ask one question? At the end of the process of them selecting the directory - it just renders out what directory they have chosen. Can we make it say something like "Your directory is c:\..... please enter that into the site" Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, just use `Echo Your directory is %r%.. Please enter that into the site.`